# Rails: Search for person with language skills - e,g, speaks "German AND English" on one-to-many table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

This must be a basic thing in rails, but I don't know how to do it.

I would like to filter participants based on the languages they speak. People can speak multiple languages, and languages are stored in their own table with a one-to-many relationship.

Now my search looks really clunky and doesn't seem to work:

```
  if @cvsearch.language.present? == true and @cvsearch.language != 0
    @p = @p.joins(:languages).where('languages.name = ?', @cvsearch.language)  
  else
    @cvsearch.language = 0
  end

  if @cvsearch.language1.present? == true and @cvsearch.language1 != 0
    @p = @p.joins(:languages).where('languages.name = ?', @cvsearch.language1)  
  end

  if @cvsearch.language2.present? == true and @cvsearch.language2 != 0
    @p = @p.joins(:languages).where('languages.name = ?', @cvsearch.language2)  
  end

  if @cvsearch.language3.present? == true and @cvsearch.language3 != 0
    @p = @p.joins(:languages).where('languages.name = ?', @cvsearch.language3)  
  end
```

The resulting SQL, slightly shortened:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "participants" INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."participant_id" = "participants"."id" WHERE (participants.id >= 2) AND (languages.name = 11) AND (languages.name = 10)[0m
```

It would be great to get a specific solution, but even better is a pointer as to where I can read up on this - what's the key word I am missing to describe this problem?

**So this is the solution I am using for now:**

```
  if @cvsearch.language1.present? == true and @cvsearch.language1 != 0
    safe_lang = ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(@cvsearch.language1)
    qry = "INNER JOIN languages l1 ON l1.participant_id = participants.id AND l1.name = " + safe_lang.to_s
    @p = @p.joins(qry)
  end
```

Works wonderfully, just need to get some feedback regarding the safety of this approach.

Comment: Yes that should be safe.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a general reference to refer you to, but this is basic SQL stuff.  Basically, the `JOIN` is performed first resulting in a number of rows and then the `WHERE` is applied, filtering the rows.  The conceptual mistake here is thinking that the `WHERE` clause will somehow apply to the full set of matched languages, but it doesn't work that way, each row of the result is considered in isolation, therefore a clause like `(languages.name = 11) AND (languages.name = 10)` will *never* return anything, because languages.name only has a single value in each row.  The query as constructed could only work for an `OR` clause, so you could say something like `WHERE (languages.name = 11) OR (languages.name = 12)`.

In order to filter down the participants you need one join for each language, so you want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participants
INNER JOIN languages l1 ON l1.participant_id = participants.id AND (languages.name = 10)
INNER JOIN languages l2 ON l2.participant_id = participants.id AND (languages.name = 11)
WHERE participants.id >= 2
```

Offhand I'm not sure of the easiest way to do this in ActiveRecord, it's not a super common query.  Your general structure should work, but with something like:

```
if @cvsearch.language1.present? == true and @cvsearch.language1 != 0
  safe_language = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(@cvssearch.language1)
  join_clause   = "INNER JOIN languages l1 ON l1.participant_id = participants.id AND language.name = #{safe_language}"
  @p = @p.joins(join_clause)
end
```

Comment: ActiveRecord does let you [fall back on SQL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), so you needn't do things the rails way.

Comment: @hd1 This is actually a perfect example of the middle-ground of that, since you put an SQL snippet for :joins (as opposed to using a symbol for an association), but while maintaining the chainability that I assume the author is depending on since this appears to be wired up to a search form with many options.

Comment: Yes, the only advantage that using AR gives you is, if you change databases, your query won't change. In my experience, databases far outlive their "sell-by dates", as it were, so it's safe using pure SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation, the code works now. You are of course right in terms of the danger when it comes to the SQL injection, I sanitize the value before it goes in. Code posted as update above, your comment regarding that solution is appreciated.